# Некорректная работа калькулятора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема, если счётчик меньше одного, идёт некорректный расчёт и добавляются непонятные суммы на выходе. Не могу понять чего не хватает.

```js
$('.dec').click(function () {
  var countner = $('.t-count').text();
  $('.t-count').text(countner/2);

  var total = $('.total-price').text();
  $('.total-price').text(total/2);

  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
  count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
  $input.val(count);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$('.inc').click(function () {
  var countner = $('.t-count').text();
  $('.t-count').text(countner*2);
  var total = $('.total-price').text();
  $('.total-price').text(total*2);

  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.cart-plus-minus {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(52, 53, 56, 0.7);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
input {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: none;
  color: #343538;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}
.qtybutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 24px;
}
.dec {
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.inc {
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-plus-minus">
  <input class="cart-plus-minus-box" type="text" name="qtybutton" value="1">
  <div class="dec qtybutton">-</div>
  <div class="inc qtybutton">+</div>
</div>
<div class="price-counter">
  <span>Площадь</span>
  <span class="t-count" style="color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 0.8);">0.5</span>
</div>
<div class="price-counter">
  <span>Цена</span>
  <span class="total-price" style="color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 0.8);">1.2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.dec').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
  if (count > 0) {
    var countner = $('.t-count').text();
    $('.t-count').text(countner / 2);
    var total = $('.total-price').text();
    $('.total-price').text(total / 2);
  } else {
    count = 1;
  }
  $input.val(count);
  $input.change();
  return false;
});

$('.inc').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  $input.change();

  var countner = $('.t-count').text();
  $('.t-count').text(countner * 2);
  var total = $('.total-price').text();
  $('.total-price').text(total * 2);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.cart-plus-minus {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(52, 53, 56, 0.7);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: none;
  color: #343538;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
}

.qtybutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 24px;
}

.dec {
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  top: 0;
}

.inc {
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-plus-minus">
  <input class="cart-plus-minus-box" type="text" name="qtybutton" value="1">
  <div class="dec qtybutton">-</div>
  <div class="inc qtybutton">+</div>
</div>
<div class="price-counter">
  <span>Площадь</span>
  <span class="t-count" style="color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 0.8);">0.5</span>
</div>
<div class="price-counter">
  <span>Цена</span>
  <span class="total-price" style="color: rgba(206, 0, 0, 0.8);">1.2</span>
</div>
```